# Odoo 13 : Enable cors origin for odoo 13 api

Tags: odoo, odoo-12, odoo-13

i tried to connect from angular post method but getting cors origin issue
this my api code at controller :

```
 @http.route('/get_students', type='json', auth='none', methods=['POST', 'OPTIONS'], website=True, csrf=False,
            cors='*')
def get_students(self, **kw):
    students_rec = http.request.env['test.student'].search([])
    students = []
    for rec in students_rec:
        vals = {
            'id': rec.id,
            'name': rec.name
        }
        students.append(vals)

    data = {'status': 200, 'result': students, 'message': 'success'}
    return data
```

Comment: Check this answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61519072/how-do-i-do-post-get-request-from-ajax-to-odoo-10-custom-module-controller-blo/61553214#61553214check the comments section "request.session.authenticate('db_name', '', '')"

Comment: @Muhammad Yusuf unfortunately it doesn't work with me .

Comment: Do you provide a body with your request? You should put an empty json `{}` in the body. I would have other comments on your code, but let's first see whether that fixes your issue, I'll then provide you with a more complete answer.

Comment: @Florimond unfortunately still the same issue , can you suggest another solution for it ?

Comment: @Khaled I would cut all the irrelevant code to your problem. Just return data = {'message': 'hello world'}, and bypass angular to call the method. Just use Chrome's console to type the following code and see what you get: fetch("http://localhost:8069/get_students",
{
    headers: {
      'Accept': 'application/json',
      'Content-Type': 'application/json'
    },
    method: "POST",
    body: "{}"
}).then(r => console.log(r.json()))

Comment: @Florimond i'm getting Fetch API cannot load localhost:8058/get_students. URL scheme must be "http" or "https" for CORS request

Comment: @Khaled Well then add "http://" before the URL in the fetch...

Comment: @Florimond getting that POST http://localhost:8058/get_students net::ERR_FAILED

Comment: @Khaled That's odd, can you somehow share a pic of the request and the result in the console? I tested it and it worked for me. Otherwise, my Discord handle is florimond (fhu)#8542 If you want we can have a quick call later.

Comment: @Florimond okay i sent you there , thanks

Comment: website=True is when you are using http type controller and you want to render some xml view in your Odoo. I think if you delete that, it'll work.

Comment: Also it's not a mistake in CORS, but it's important to know: When we just want retrieve data and show it, we use GET method instead of POST,.

Answer (score 0):

I did the same but unfortunately  same issue.

But now, I found a solution using NGINX Proxy. This is config file of NGINX, you can adapt it and it will work for you.

Regards.**strong text**

```
#user  nobody;
worker_processes  1;

#error_log  logs/error.log;
#error_log  logs/error.log  notice;
#error_log  logs/error.log  info;

#pid        logs/nginx.pid;


events {
    worker_connections  1024;
}


http {
    include       mime.types;
    default_type  application/octet-stream;

    #log_format  main  '$remote_addr - $remote_user [$time_local] "$request" '
    #                  '$status $body_bytes_sent "$http_referer" '
    #                  '"$http_user_agent" "$http_x_forwarded_for"';

    #access_log  logs/access.log  main;

    sendfile        on;
    #tcp_nopush     on;

    #keepalive_timeout  0;
    keepalive_timeout  65;

    #gzip  on;
    
    
    upstream odooserver {
     server 127.0.0.1:9092;
    }
    map $http_origin:$host $origin {
        default "";
        http://localhost:9092 $http_origin;
    }
    
    server {
    
         listen 80;
         server_name domainname.com;

         access_log C:/nginx-1.20.1/logs/testing-access.log;
         error_log C:/nginx-1.20.1/logs/testing-error.log;

         proxy_read_timeout 720s;
         proxy_connect_timeout 720s;
         proxy_send_timeout 720s;
         proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Host $host;
         proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
         proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
         proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;

         location / {
         
         proxy_hide_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin';
         proxy_hide_header  Access-Control-Allow-Origin;
              if ($request_method = 'OPTIONS') {
        add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' '*';
        add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Methods' 'GET, POST, OPTIONS';
        #
        # Custom headers and headers various browsers *should* be OK with but aren't
        #
        add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Headers' '*' always;
        #
        # Tell client that this pre-flight info is valid for 20 days
        #
        add_header 'Access-Control-Max-Age' 1728000;
        add_header 'Content-Type' 'text/plain; charset=utf-8';
        add_header 'Content-Length' 0;
        return 204;
     }
     if ($request_method = 'POST') {
        add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' '*' always;
        add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Methods' 'GET, POST, OPTIONS' always;
        add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Headers' '*' always;
        add_header 'Access-Control-Expose-Headers' '*' always;
     }
     if ($request_method = 'GET') {
        add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' '*' always;
        add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Methods' 'GET, POST, OPTIONS' always;
        add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Headers' '*' always;
        add_header 'Access-Control-Expose-Headers' '*' always;
     }
            proxy_redirect off;
            proxy_pass http://odooserver;
         }

         location ~* /web/static/ {
             proxy_cache_valid 200 90m;
             proxy_buffering on;
             expires 864000;
             proxy_pass http://odooserver;
         }

         gzip_types text/css text/less text/plain text/xml application/xml application/json application/javascript;
         gzip on;
     }

  
        


    # another virtual host using mix of IP-, name-, and port-based configuration
    #
    #server {
    #    listen       8000;
    #    listen       somename:8080;
    #    server_name  somename  alias  another.alias;

    #    location / {
    #        root   html;
    #        index  index.html index.htm;
    #    }
    #}


    # HTTPS server
    #
    #server {
    #    listen       443 ssl;
    #    server_name  localhost;

    #    ssl_certificate      cert.pem;
    #    ssl_certificate_key  cert.key;

    #    ssl_session_cache    shared:SSL:1m;
    #    ssl_session_timeout  5m;

    #    ssl_ciphers  HIGH:!aNULL:!MD5;
    #    ssl_prefer_server_ciphers  on;

    #    location / {
    #        root   html;
    #        index  index.html index.htm;
    #    }
    #}

}
```