# How to allow CORS in odoo 10

Tags: python, cors, odoo, odoo-10

is there any solution to add CORS in odoo 10?, i want to access this restful API:

```
@validate_token
@http.route("/api/survey.survey/all", type="http", auth="none", methods=["GET", "OPTIONS"], csrf=False, cors='*') #Keperluan Web
def get_survey_survey_all(self, id=None, **payload):
    model = "v.survey.survey"
    ioc_name = model
    _model = request.env[self._model].sudo().search([("model", "=", model)], limit=1)
    
    custFields = ['id', 'title', 'stage_id', 'date_start', 'date_end', 'narasi', 'tot_comp_survey', 'department_id', 'responden'
                    , 'jenis_penelitian_id', 'polda_id', 'polres_id', 'fungsi', 'tahun', 'public_url', 'result_url']
    custDomain = [("public_publish", "=", "1")]

    if _model:
        domain, fields, offset, limit, order = extract_arguments(payload)
        fields = custFields
        domain = custDomain
        data = (request.env[_model.model].sudo().search_read(
            domain = domain,
            fields = fields,
            offset = offset,
            limit = limit,
            order = order
        ))
        
        if data:
            return valid_response(data)
        else:
            return valid_response(data)
    return invalid_response(
        "Invalid object model",
        "The model %s is not available in the registry." % ioc_name
    )
```

i've add **cors='*'** but it's still got an error because **access_token** not allowed from header **Access-Control-Allow-Headers**

and this is my valid response code

```
def valid_response(data, status=200):
    """Valid Response
    This will be return when the http request was successfully processed."""
    data = {"count": len(data), "data": data}
    return werkzeug.wrappers.Response(
        status=status,
        content_type="application/json; charset=utf-8;", 
        headers=[
            ("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "access_token")
            ],
        response=json.dumps(data),
    )
```

Comment: See [an alternative option](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72936992/react-native-call-odoo-api-via-axios-struggling-with-cors) that did the trick for me.

Comment: [Check this question seems similar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61519072/how-do-i-do-post-get-request-from-ajax-to-odoo-10-custom-module-controller-blo/61553214#61553214)

Comment: Thank you, but i've already solved this problem